# can't change angular's material select placeholder color

Tags: angular, angular-material

im having problem with setting placeholder's color to white on the dark background, when setting to white, it has weird stroke like this:
[image]

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-twbzew-ealbnk

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-select [ngClass]="className" placeholder="{{someText}}">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let item of items" [value]="item.value">
            {{ item.viewValue }}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>


.basic-container {
    background: black;

  padding: 5px;
}


.class1  .mat-select-placeholder {
  color:white !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There appears to be a second placeholder element that sits in front.

You can modify the CSS to also make that 2nd element white, like so:

```
.class1  .mat-select-placeholder, 
.class1 + .mat-input-placeholder-wrapper .mat-input-placeholder {
    color:white !important;
}
```

**[Here is a fork of the Stackblitz to demonstrate](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-twbzew-mkqwdb?file=styles.css)**

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this

:host /deep/ .mat-form-field-label-wrapper .mat-form-field-label {
    color:white !important;
}
```